# HTML link to generic page that displays specific images

Tags: html

I have a simple HTML page with a table containing multiple rows. Each row has a cell with a hyperlink to another HTML page named "photos.html". Currently the "photos.html" page displays every single image linked to from the main page. I would like to change this so that if the user clicks a hyperlink on the main page, the "photos.html" page is opened but only the images relating to the specific row are displayed.

Here is a simplified example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
        <A HREF="photos.html" TARGET="_blank">Link 1</A> <!-- Open "photos.html" with Link 1 images only -->
        <A HREF="photos.html" TARGET="_blank">Link 2</A> <!-- Open "photos.html" with Link 2 images only -->
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Is this possible in HTML?

Comment: use anchor links <a href="photos.html#row1" target="_blank">link1</a> [link](http://help.typepad.com/anchor-tags.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use anchors. I just want a generic page that displays the appropriate images based on the row selected in the table on the main page.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Jquery

```
$("a").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var url=$(this).attr("href");
  $.ajax({
               url: url,
               success: function(data) {
                   $("img", data).each(function() {
                      alert( $(this).attr("src") );
                   });
               }
   });     
});
```

> Update

```
</html>
    <head>
    <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
       $("a").click(function(event){
          var anchor=$(this);
          event.preventDefault();
          var url=$(this).attr("href");
          $.ajax({
                  url: url,
                  success: function(data) {
                  $("img", data).each(function() {
                         //var img='<img id="theImg" src="'+($(this).attr("src"))+'" />';
                         anchor.next("div.images").append($(this));
                   });
              }
           });     
        }); 
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <A HREF="photos.html" TARGET="_blank">Link 1</A> <!-- Open "photos.html" with Link 1 images only -->
        <div class="images">

        </div>
        <A HREF="photos.html" TARGET="_blank">Link 2</A> <!-- Open "photos.html" with Link 2 images only -->
        <div class="images">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`data` object containing the page's html code.
In this line `alert( $(this).attr("src") );` you can access all the elements.
For example : Get all `DIV` tags

```
$("div", data).each(function() {
    alert( $(this).attr("id") );
});
```

Comment: I have never used Jquery before. Could you please tell me where this code is placed? Do I need to change anything (like url, data etc) to get it to work?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I have confused the matter with the example I gave. As per my description in the original post, the hyperlinks are in a cell in a table so I don't think I can use <div> tags. The hyperlinks are also text links, not image links. Can your solution be modified to suit this arrangement?